# Update googlemap Camera location every time location changes

Tags: android, google-maps, locationlistener

I would like the camera to automatically update and move every time the location changes. Is this possible? I am using onMapReady() and onLocationChanged().

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener, OnMapReadyCallback {
```

OnCreate()

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    locationManager = (LocationManager) (getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE));


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //TODO: Consider calling
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PICK_FINE_LOCATION_REQUEST);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PICK_COARSE_LOCATION_REQUEST);
        return;
    }


    locationCurrent = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    onLocationChanged(locationCurrent);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 5, this);

     mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}
```

onMapReady()

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //TODO: Consider calling
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PICK_FINE_LOCATION_REQUEST);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PICK_COARSE_LOCATION_REQUEST);
        return;
    }
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(locationCurrent.getLatitude(),locationCurrent.getLongitude());
    CameraPosition cameraPosition= new CameraPosition(latLng,15,0,0);
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
    googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    map = googleMap;
```

I have a global variable: Googlemap map;

onLocationChanged()

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    //Log.d("UPDATEMAP","onLocationChanged");
    UpdateMap(map,location);}
```

I made a method called UpdateMap()

```
    public void UpdateMap(GoogleMap map,Location location){
    Log.d("UPDATEMAP","UpdateMap");
    LatLng latLngUpdate = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition(latLngUpdate,15,0,0);
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
}
```

The error I am getting is that the global variable is equal to null even though I set it in onMapReady(). 
Any Help will be appreciated.
Thanks Ritvik.

Comment: What variable is null?

Comment: Probably `onLocationChanged` is being called before `onMapReady`. Request location updates after onMapReady is called

Comment: The googlemap map is null

Comment: Thanks Juan Cruz Soler I didnt realize that this simple fix would make it work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm glad to help you. I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `map` variable is null because `onLocationChanged` is being called before `onMapReady`.
To fix it request location updates in the method `onMapReady` after the variable is assigned.